# COPY failed error dockerfile while using gcloud command

Tags: java, docker, jar, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

Some strange error has hit, this code was working earlier.

My tree:

```
LM0002254:SellerService$ ls -lrt
total 61512
drwxr-xr-x   3 tarun  826136866        96 Feb  8 14:16 gradle
-rw-r--r--   1 tarun  826136866       168 Apr 23 13:26 gradle.properties
-rwxr-xr-x   1 tarun  826136866      5766 Apr 23 13:26 gradlew
-rw-r--r--   1 tarun  826136866      2763 Apr 23 13:26 gradlew.bat
-rw-r--r--   1 tarun  826136866        36 Apr 23 13:26 settings.gradle.kts
drwxr-xr-x   5 tarun  826136866       160 Apr 23 13:26 src
-rw-r--r--   1 tarun  826136866      3868 Apr 23 22:39 build.gradle.kts
drwxr-xr-x  23 tarun  826136866       736 Apr 23 23:15 build
-rw-r--r--   1 tarun  826136866  31282686 Apr 23 23:16 SellerService-jvm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rwxr-xr-x   1 tarun  826136866       214 Apr 23 23:22 install-cloud.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 tarun  826136866       148 Apr 23 23:39 Dockerfile
```

Docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY SellerService-jvm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ./

CMD ["java", "-jar", "./SellerService-jvm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Am getting below error, not sure why. This same piece of code was running yesterday.

cmd which am using on gcloud.

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/<projectname>
```

Error am getting:

```
Step 1/5 : FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
8-jre-alpine: Pulling from library/openjdk
e7c96db7181b: Already exists
f910a506b6cb: Already exists
b6abafe80f63: Pulling fs layer
b6abafe80f63: Verifying Checksum
b6abafe80f63: Download complete
b6abafe80f63: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f362b165b870ef129cbe730f29065ff37399c0aa8bcab3e44b51c302938c9193
Status: Downloaded newer image for openjdk:8-jre-alpine
 ---> f7a292bbb70c
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 76b0acf0c246
Removing intermediate container 76b0acf0c246
 ---> 4afe2649b879
Step 3/5 : COPY SellerService-jvm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar .
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder987483752/SellerService-jvm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: Try this command `docker build . -f dockerfile` to build

Comment: Am using gcloud cmds, I have not used docker cmd much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker is reading my .gitignore content and ignoring files and folder in it. I have ignored jar files in gitignore so its ignoring that while copying. Need to make sure .gitignore file is not having those files ignored which you are copying in docker file.